# How can we fetch secrets from keyvault in Azure DataBricks if we select "Allow public access from specific virtual networks and IP addresses"

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

What will be possible solution for this problem?

Using Pi-spark language in notebooks, Does any script be using for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Chen Hirsh, Go to azure key vault -> Networking -> + Add Allow public access from specific virtual networks and IP addresses.

With the above Virtual Network access ,you can try to access the key Vault using pyspark, I got required result as below:

> **Note:** Make sure to create scope to connect key vault with azure databricks: Creating  [**Secret Scope**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui) ->  **Go to azure vault**  -> Enter the  **Vault URI** .(for  **Example**,  `https://<key_vault_name>.vault.azure.net/`) and **Resource ID**  -> Go to  **Properties tab**  of an Azure Key Vault in your  **Azure portal**  you get both  **Vault URI**  and  **Resource ID**.

[image]

> **Sample Code**

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential as cs


kv_URI = "Vault_URI"
TENANT_ID = '<Tenent_Id>'
CLIENT_ID = '<Client_Id>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<Client_Secret>'
credentials = cs(
            tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

def set_secret(secret_name,secret_value):
        print(credentials)
        secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_URI, credential=credentials)
        secret = secret_client.set_secret(secret_name,secret_value,enabled=True)
        secr_dic={}
        secr_dic['name']=secret.name
        secr_dic['value']=secret.value
        secr_dic['properties']=secret.properties.version
        return secr_dic
#Use keyvalut secret name    
x1=set_secret('demo1','value')
print(x1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set Azure keyvault to the same virtual network, so databricks can access keyvault.
There are setting in keyvault under "Networking", the same as you have on databricks.